# How to create postgres TYPE that automatically converts text to lowercase?

Tags: postgresql

I need a data type, call it `LTEXT` that operates identically to `TEXT` (or possibly CITEXT if that has benefits?) in every way except that it coerces all values to their `lower()` version. So for example:

```
SELECT 'AbC'::LTEXT; => 'abc'

and

SELECT 'AbC'::LTEXT = 'abc'::LTEXT; => true
SELECT 'AbC'::LTEXT = 'abc'::TEXT; => true
```

If it were possible to have internal functions with `DOMAIN`s then this would be easy to do, but since thats not an option, I assume that a `TYPE` is the only way to do it. But I don't really know anything about how to make an internal input and output function. It seems to get complicated pretty quickly. If there is an easy way to keep this, seemingly simple task, simple then I'd be grateful for the help.

Comment: Data normalization is typically done in the import layer. You could write a domain that only accepts lower case text. `create domain ltext as text check(lower(value) = value);` What is the purpose of lower casing everything?

Comment: It already exists; check out the type [citext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html). It will NOT actually convert the text to lower case but will return True for `SELECT 'AbC'::CITEXT = 'abc'::CITEXT; ` If you have not already doen so you will need to install the extension `citext`.

Comment: I'm already aware of CITEXT and DOMAIN options as I mentioned. DOMAIN puts the burden on each and every single point of entry to make sure things are lower(). I'm not exactly sure what you mean or assume by "at the import layer" but it would surely be an anti-pattern to do it that way in my context. Consider imports coming from various different parts of code. The best solution is one, centralized place that regardless of where or when an insert/update event happens the recorded value is always normalized to lower(). I cannot imagine why one would want to do it any other way.

Comment: Granted, I could make a trigger for this, but if I want to have this kind of pattern for many tables/columns... that means many triggers for each. It would make so much more sense to just have a type that does it in one place and it applies globally.